# Modyfication of already existing beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I have an application written in Java (8) + spring boot and a frontend in angular. The application has automatic sending of e-mails     `(@Scheduler)`     and the user has the option of modifying e-mail settings, e.g. login password to e-mail or server and this is where the problem begins. Settings are stored in the database and in the application as `@Bean` -**SettingsBean**. How can I update the content of an already injected bean to another instance, e.g. **SettingsBean** is injected into **`JavaMailSender`** at startup with default settings, so after changing the user, `@ bean` setting changes but the values ​​in **JavaMailSender** do not. How to solve it?

Comment: I would not store changeable data as a bean or use "session/request" scope bean for that data. But for scheduler action I would retrieve them from Db only.

Comment: i actually had to store them in some type of Bean because setting include also for e.x few schedule timers and other data's. Only problem i had is how to catch this bean in running program , change his data and all its values ​​that are currently used somewhere. Session bean won't consider my problem in my opinion

Comment: 1. what about saving data in DB and fetching them when You need them + adding some cache and evicting on update. 

2. You can use concurrentMap in bean to store config per user, but it won't be memory efficient but You will not have concurrency issue.

Comment: 3. You can just update bean (which is a singleton in application.) bean.setThings(xx)

Comment: I already have function to update bean , but problem starts in the moment when this bean is autowired into another bean (in my ex SettingsBean is autowired into JavaMailSender) and i have no idea how to update JavaMailSender with new values, where also JMS didn't have any property it is just a configuration class which create this JavaMailSender and return him into upper service (some typer of watcher )

Comment: So my common problem is how to after changes in settings bean , reacrete JavaMailSender with chenged values and inject this bean into upper service

Comment: Not sure why You want to recreate JavaMailSender if Your SettingsBean will be updated. You should just use new properties of SettingsBean in javaMailSender. 

1. But to propose some solution.  I would not create JavaMailSender as a bean, but I would initiate it in some MailJMSWrapper with autowired settingsBean . Then I would create JmSender manually and copy settingsBean data and compare with data at execution if different then create new JMSender if old use old instance.

Comment: 2. Second approach would be with events to send event to Wrapper whenever setting bean was changed to initiate new JMSender.

Comment: idea with a wrapper works great ,thanks a lot @JohnTribe!

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions not sure which will fit better but:

1. Create Wrapper and recreate JavaMailSender

I would not create `JavaMailSender` as a bean, but I would initiate it in some `MailJMSWrapper` with @autowired `SettingsBean` .
Then I would create JavaMailSender manually and copy settingsBean data and compare with data at execution.
If different then create new `JavaMailSender`.
If old use old instance.

2. Use Events + Wrapper

Second approach would be with events to send event to Wrapper whenever `SettingsBean` was changed to initiate new `JavaMailSender`.